# Calling RestTemplate with Ribbon Interceptor

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, resttemplate, spring-cloud-netflix

I am trying to use `RestTemplate` with `@EnableDiscoveryClient` which ends up calling the Ribbon Interceptor. Down the call stack, the following call ends up being made:

```
org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonClientHttpRequestFactory$
RibbonHttpRequest.getBodyInternal(RibbonClientHttpRequestFactory.java:105)
```

Now, here is the code of this `getBodyInternal` method:

```
 @Override
 protected OutputStream getBodyInternal(HttpHeaders headers) throws IOException {
        throw new RuntimeException("Not implemented");
 }
```

My question is what cases lead to this not implemented method and how can I avoid that? I am using `RestTemplate.postForLocation`. Is it a general assumption that this method should not be called with Ribbon interceptor?

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: Using 1.0.2.RELEASE. It appears to happen with RestTemplate.exchange as well. Also worth noting that I have no manual interceptor. All I do is declare restTemplate as @Autowired.

Comment: Try with version `1.0.3.RELEASE` which is part of `spring-cloud-starter-parent:Angel.SR3`.  That method has been implemented.

Comment: Thanks. That solves the issue. Please add your comment as answer if you don't mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with version `1.0.3.RELEASE` which is part of `spring-cloud-starter-parent:Angel.SR3`. That method has been implemented.